# How to send token to other paths?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

```
@PostMapping("login")
public String postLogin(@RequestParam Map<String, String> body) {
    log.info(body);

    Optional<String> token = authService.login(body.get("email"), 
                                             body.get("password"), 
                                             body.get("rememberMe"));
    if (token.equals(Optional.empty())) {
            return "redirect:/login-error";
    }else {
        log.info("POST MAPPING SUCCESSFUL " + token.orElse(null) );
        response.add("Authorization",token.orElse(null));
        return "redirect:/main-page-authorized";} }
```

**  Here I am able to get token ,according to useremail. It generate token. But I do not know how to send token to browser and each request it recognize token.At the same time , I need to redirect to main-page-authorized. How can I do both of them?**

Comment: Instead of "response.add", have you tried "response. setHeader(token.orElse(null))" ? Also, shouldn't you receive "HttpServletResponse response" as a param for this method as well?

Comment: Yes you are right, it was deleted,sorry. But when I try response,setHeader()  also, next page does not recognize token. Actually, token will be shown null(

Comment: Yeah, but log in else statement shows token generation. It is generated

Comment: I think problem is header is not shown, or missing after redirecting

Comment: From all other places I read, the "redirect://" because it happens on the client-side, the headers won't be present when setting it here.

Answer (score 0):

"login" is not a controller responsibility scope. Checks and redirects must be specified in the Spring Security configuration. For example:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and().formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
}
```

I highly recommend learning this.

Comment: Yeah, but I can not see any tutorial that customize login page. After all, my question is not about it . My question is to send token to other pages